# Detect if the user pressed Cancel on clone dialog

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

In my maxscript, I am using this command:

```
actionMan.executeAction 0 "40213"  -- Edit: Clone
```

Is there a way to detect if the user presses the "Cancel" on the clone dialog, because if he does the script will affect the original mesh instead of the new one created by the clone function.

Note: I know there is a way to skip this dialog with #nodialog, but this is not good for me, as I want to allow the user to choose if he wants to clone, instance or reference the original geometry.

Comment: Are you the one throwing up the clone dialog? Or are you just trying to respond to a general clone event?

Answer (score 0):

Check `objects.count` before and after the call. If no objects were cloned, they will be identical.